# How can I make playback zoom start in small steps rather than going to 1:1 with Magic Lantern?

Tags: canon-60d, firmware-hacks, rear-lcd, image-review, magic-lantern

I just got a brand spanking new Canon 60D with the Magic Lantern custom firmware, and I love it except for one thing: when you are looking at the images you have taken, and you press the zoom button, it zooms in as far as possible. I assume this is probably 1:1.

When I press the zoom button, how can I get it to zoom to the least amount? I have looked in the manual and I can't find anything.

Comment: After looking for a long time, I found a setting in Magic Lantern that seemed to fix it. I am not sure if it was caused by Magic Lantern but I assume it was.

Comment: Oh hey. Mentioning that you're using a custom firmware is a pretty key detail!

Comment: Could you also tell others which setting to use?

Comment: I removed magic lantern after that so I don't know what setting. Sorry I forgot to mention it!

Comment: @SamB: Please use comments for those kinds of updates, or even update your question. You did not actually provide an answer, so I've converted it to a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Magic Lantern under 'prefs' under 'image review settings'. Turn off 'quick zoom'

All done. Enjoy.