# Can I make my Canon dslr instantly zoom to 1:1 after shooting a picture?

Tags: canon, zoom, magnification, image-review, camera-controls

When you shoot a photo, your picture is displayed onscreen. It's said to be possible to zoom in the picture, but pressing the zoom buttons do not zoom but activate their second function. So is it possible to zoom inside a picture when reviewing it just after shoot, and is it possible to zoom to the 1:1 level in one press ?

My question is mainly about the EOS 400D, and xxxD models, but any feedback about higher-end models will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you can do it with Magic Lantern, as here's a question from someone [wanting it to _not_ do that](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18457/how-can-i-make-playback-zoom-start-in-small-steps-rather-than-going-to-11-with)

Answer (score 6):

Only way I could think of is MagicLantern. I installed it on my 1100D yesterday night and I instantly wanted to disable that feature.